# Custom sidebar not showing in the dashboard

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

I am trying to create a new sidebar. For that I have used the following code:

In `functions.php`

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar();

if ( function_exists ('register_sidebar')) {
register_sidebar ('sidebar-custom');
}
```

Then I created a file called `sidebar-custom.php`.The code for that file is as follows

```
<ul class=”sidebar”>
     <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') ||
           !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-custom') ) : ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

But the sidebar area is not visible in the dashboard.I know I have done something terribly wrong. But dont know what it is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Register sidebar.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse_123456_widgets_init' );
function wpse_123456_widgets_init() {
    $args = array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ),
        'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
        'description'   => '',
         'class'         => '',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</li>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

    if ( function_exists ('register_sidebar')) {
      register_sidebar( $args );
    }
}
```

Call the sidebar.

```
if ( is_active_sidebar('unique-sidebar-id') {
 dynamic_sidebar('unique-sidebar-id') );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. To register the sidebar you need to pass a minimum of the 'id'.

```
if ( function_exists ('register_sidebar')) {
  register_sidebar(array('id'=>'custom'));
}
```

[Despite the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar#New_way_of_adding_sidebars), I cannot get the sidebar to show up using only `register_sidebar('custom');`

That will make the sidebar show up on the backend. [See the Codex for other parameters.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

Secondly, there is nothing to load `sidebar-custom.php`. `dynamic_sidebar('custom')` would load a file named `sidebar-custom.php`, at least the Codex appears to suggest that, but since you have that function call inside `sidebar-custom.php` it never gets to run.

Third, you have curly quotes in you code. Look at the quotes around the class name.

So, to make this work put the following in `functions.php` (same as above):

```
if ( function_exists ('register_sidebar')) {
  register_sidebar(array('id'=>'custom'));
}
```

Place the following in the template file where you want to the sidebar to load but not in `sidebar-custom.php`.

```
 if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('custom') ) :
 endif;
```

Your sidebar should now work, but again [despite the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar#New_way_of_adding_sidebars) or possibly the Codex is just very confusing on the point, I can't get your `sidebar-custom.php` file to load.

To do that I have to explicitly use `get_sidebar ('custom');`

The more I worked on this, the more I came to believe that the Codex is poorly written when it come to custom sidebar files. The truth is in there but it is hard to see. Hope this helps.